# Deploying ambassador to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, ambassador

I've been learning about how to deploy ambassador on kubernetes on minikube by [this](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/getting-started/) tutorial, and that works as I can see the page for successfully installed ambassador. The main problem is, when I try to change the image of the UI such that it should open other app in the link, it opens the same successfull page of ambassador.

Previous `tour.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tour
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: tour-ui_mapping
      prefix: /
      service: tour:5000
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: tour-backend_mapping
      prefix: /backend/
      service: tour:8080
      labels:
        ambassador:
          - request_label:
            - backend
spec:
  ports:
  - name: ui
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  - name: backend
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: tour
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tour
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tour
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tour
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tour-ui
        image: quay.io/datawire/tour:ui-0.2.1
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5000
      - name: quote
        image: quay.io/datawire/tour:backend-0.2.1
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
            memory: 100Mi
```

modified `tour.yaml`(removed backend and changed the image)

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tour
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: tour-ui_mapping
      prefix: /
      service: tour:5000
spec:
  ports:
  - name: ui
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: tour
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tour
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tour
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tour
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tour-ui
        image: quay.io/integreatly/tutorial-web-app:2.10.5
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 5000
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.1"
            memory: 100Mi
```

`ambassador-service.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
   - port: 80
     targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    service: ambassador
```

Please help, I'm really confused what is the cause behind it and how I can resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Alohomora! This behaviour is really weird. Did you actually deploy tour.yaml again in the same namespace? Can you try changing "name: tour-ui_mapping" to something else? You can also see the log of your tour pod (`kubectl logs {pod's name}`) to check if the requests are arriving there.

Comment: @VictorVal, I did change the name of "name:tour-ui_mapping" to "sample-ui_mapping", but it doesn't change the behaviour of opening the ambassador page. I also deployed tour.yaml after changing it by : $ kubectl apply -f tour.yaml but still getting the same issue.

Comment: @VictorVal, when I changed the image to "quay.io/frank_dasilva/node-js-hello-world:72" and didn't change anything like name:tour-ui_mapping, that works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing above is *replacing* the `tour` Kubernetes `service` and `deployment` with your own alternative. This is a bit of an unusual pattern; I'd suspect that there's probably a typo somewhere which means Kubernetes isn't picking up on your change.

I'd suggest creating a unique `test` Kubernetes `service` and `deployment`, and pointing the `image` in your `deployment` to your new image. Then you can register a new prefix with Ambassador.

You can also look at the Ambassador diagnostics (see https://www.getambassador.io/reference/diagnostics/) which will tell you which routes are registered with Ambassador.